# Angular: how to wait for final result of method while mapping is waiting for multiple api calls?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method in my service where I'm downloading a context for my custom components. The problem is that for my components I'm getting a field for attachments that contains id. Then I have to use this id to download attachments and add them to parent object.

This is my method:

```
  getComponentContext(componentConfigId: string, diaryInstanceId: string, endpoint: string, inputTypeId: string, UserID?: string) {
    return this.apiService.post(`componentinstances/${endpoint}`,
      {
        ComponentConfigID: componentConfigId,
        DairyInstanceID: diaryInstanceId,
        InputTypeID: inputTypeId,
        UserID
      })
      .pipe(
        switchMap(result => {
          if (result.Records && result.Records.length) {
            result.Records.forEach(record => {
              if (record.Fields) {
                const attachmentField = record.Fields.find(rec => rec.Type === 'Attachment');
                if (attachmentField) {
                  const folderDetails = this.documentsApiService.getFileDetailsByFolderID(attachmentField.Value).toPromise();
                  record.documentsFolder = folderDetails;
                }
              }
            });
          }
          return result;
        }),
        retry(2));
  }
```

So I want to `return result;` only when all of `this.documentsApiService.getFileDetailsByFolderID` calls are finished and `record.documentsFolder` have their values. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RxJS `forkJoin` function to trigger the multiple HTTP request in parallel. To impose your conditions, you could use ternary operator with RxJS `of` function to emit the value as-is for failed conditions. And lastly use `map` operator with spread syntax to transform the output.

Try the following

```js
getComponentContext(
  componentConfigId: string, 
  diaryInstanceId: string, 
  endpoint: string, 
  inputTypeId: 
  string, 
  UserID?: string
) {
  const load = {
      ComponentConfigID: componentConfigId,
      DairyInstanceID: diaryInstanceId,
      InputTypeID: inputTypeId,
      UserID
  };

  return this.apiService.post(`componentinstances/${endpoint}`, load).pipe(
    switchMap(result => 
      (!!result.Records && result.Records.length)
        ? forkJoin(
          result.Records.map(record => {
            if (!!record.Fields) {
              const attachmentField = record.Fields.find(rec => rec.Type === 'Attachment');
              if (attachmentField) {
                return this.documentsApiService.getFileDetailsByFolderID(attachmentField.Value).pipe(
                  map((folderDetails: any) => 
                    ({ ...record, documentsFolder: folderDetails })
                  )
                );
              }
            }
            return of(record);
          })
        ).pipe(
            map(records => ({ ...result, Records: records }))
          )
        : of(result)
    )
  );
}
```